# How to edit the database in .NET 5.0 ( Code first approach )

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm learning .NET 5.0 and now I've just created the database on SQL server using code first approach (Migrations), But then I've realized somethings on the database need to be modified and I need to delete a table from the DB and modify a relation between another table, so my question is : Should I go directly to the VS and delete the model which is responsible for that table from the project and the DbContext and just edit the relations and add it as a migration?, or there is a specific way to edit the DB?

Answer (score 1):

When using the CodeFirst approach changes should always be made to the model first and then applies to the database though migrations. So your first apporach is the one to go with.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, you can try the following steps to modify the table in the database.

**First**, we need to make changes to the model.(such as delete model class)

**Second**, we can rebuild the project again.

**Third**, please run the following command in the nuget-package console.

```
Enable-Migrations

Add-Migration First-Migration

Update-Database
```

**Finally**, upon you see the following code, which represents that you have made changes to the database.(I add a column to a table and delete a table)

```
public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Students", "Age", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            DropTable("dbo.Courses");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to edit the database in codeFirst approach is you need to make changes on the model first , then migrate and update the database.So you can proceed with your intial choice.